# Predict words in a given corpus from jumbled incomplete characters

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

A complete newbie to data science. I have to predict the word using characters given. But the characters given can be in any order, and some might be missing or wrong. The problem is I get too many suggestions that arent right.

## Trial 1:

I have tried permutating the given characters and checking if it is a valid english word : https://pastebin.com/ZUZDZPPa
This does not take into account autocorrect like features.
With autocorrect: https://pastebin.com/mDjVn0Rz

## Trial 2:

Tried limiting editdistance (levenshtein distance) to 2 and used my custom corpus that I built as I knew the context of the word (Occupations or hobbies).
https://pastebin.com/iC5TYxzS 
The problem is that the predictions I get arent close to the answer. I got pretty good results in Trial 2, but I am wondering if there was a better approach as edit distance of 2 is pretty limiting.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data? I’m confused as to whether the characters are guaranteed to be out of order, or if it’s just a likely occurrence.

Comment: I can give you the context. These characters are extracted from OCR of painted letters lying around the ground randomly. Sample (sorry its blurred, its usually better) : https://i.imgur.com/T6YM80x.jpg

Comment: Huh ok yeah that’s gonna be a tough one. Thanks for sharing the context!